# How do I moq a ISingleResult? Should I? or there is a better method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, moq

I have an action method like this in my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDatacontext())
    {
        var results = db.GetRecordSets(arg1, ....).ToList();
        // use results as list
    }

    return View();
}
```

and I wanted to start making tests for it (yes, after it was built, not before... but the code was written before I started to use TDD so... )

and I figured out that adding a property such as this one to the controller

```
public delegate NorthwindDatacontext ContextBuilderDelegate();

public ContextBuilderDelegate ContextBuilder { get; set; }
```

I could add in the constructor something like this...

```
ContextBuilder = () => new NorthwindDatacontext();
```

then I could test the ActionMethod setting the ContextBuilder property with a mock of NorthwindDatacontext

```
var controller              = new MyController();
var mockDataContext         = new Mock<NorthwindDatacontext>();
controller.ContextBuilder   = () => mockDataContext.Object;
```

But... I found no way to use this because all methods of NorthwindDatacontext use ISingleResult as returnType and I cant find the way to create an object with that interface.
I've tried this

```
var theResult                  = new List<GetRecordSetsResult>();
// fill the data structure here with the provided result...

mockDataContext.Setup(c => c. GetRecordSets()).Returns(theResult as
                                            ISingleResult<GetRecordSetsResult>);
```

but it doesn't work because theResult is null when converted to ISingleResult.

Is there any way to create a ISingleResult object to test this way or I'm doing the incorrect way to do things here?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thanks, your question and the first answer really helped me solve me problem.

Answer (score 5):

`ToList()` is an extension method for IEnumerable, which is easy to mock, because it only has one member method -- `GetEnumerator()`.

Still you might have problems mocking NorthwindDataContext class, if its methods are not virtual...

Anyways, that's how I solved a similar problem in my sandbox, hope it helps:

```
public class MyType
{
    public virtual ISingleResult<int> ReturnSomeResult() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var mockMyType = new Mock<MyType>();
    var mockSingleResult = new Mock<ISingleResult<int>>();
    IEnumerable<int> someEnumerable = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
    mockSingleResult.Setup(result => result.GetEnumerator()).Returns(someEnumerable.GetEnumerator());
    mockMyType.Setup(myType => myType.ReturnSomeResult()).Returns(mockSingleResult.Object);

    Assert.AreEqual(15, mockMyType.Object.ReturnSomeResult().ToList().Sum());
}
```

Comment: Great answer... this is what I would be doing too.

Comment: Sorry, I feel like a fool here because I cant see how I can solve my problem. I see its a good approach but it doesn't solves what I need. I was taking a look into Rob Conery's MVC Storefront videos and I can see the repository pattern is what I need but that is not easily implemented with LinqToSql Data Contexts as I can see.

Comment: Works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

I created a class that implemented ISingleResult and just put a List in it.  I am fairly new to this type of coding, so while this worked for me, use at your own risk (and if you see holes post a comment).

```
class SingleResult<T>:ISingleResult<T>
{
    readonly List<T> _list = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _list.Add(item);
    }

    #region Interface Items

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public object ReturnValue { get { return _list; } }

    public void Dispose() { }

    #endregion
}
```

This can then be used to return in part of a mock.  This is how I ended up using it with Rhino Mocks:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomething()
{
    //Arrange
    // Make a data context and DAL
    var _ctx = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDataClassesDataContext>();
    var someDALClass = new SomeDALClass(_ctx);

    User testUser = UserObjectHelper.TestUser();
    SingleResult<User> userList = new SingleResult<User> { testUser };

    // Indicate that we expect a call the to sproc GetUserByUserID
    _ctx.Expect(x => x.GetUserByUserID(testUser.UserID)).Return(userList);

    //Act
    someDALClass.UpdateUser(testUser);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(SomeTestCondition());
}
```

Comment: Very good, +1. I am using this class with a couple of changes: 1. `_list` is an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>`. 2. I pass a ready to use collection in the class constructor instead of having an `Add` method.